# Cumulative Compoud Interest Calculation(Oracle Database 11g Release 2)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a requirement to calculate rolling compound interest on several accounts in pl/sql. I was looking for help/advice on how to script calculate these calculations. The calculations I need are in the last two columns of the output below (INTERESTAMOUNT AND RUNNING TOTAL). I found similar examples of this on here, but nothing specifically fitting these requirements in pl/sql. I am also new to CTE/Recursive Techniques and the Model technique I found required a specific iteration which would be variable in this case. Please see  my problem below:

Calculations:

- INTERESTAMOUNT = (Previous Year RUNNING TOTAL+ Current Year AMOUNT) * INTEREST_RATE
- RUNNINGTOTAL = (Previous Year RUNNING TOTAL+ Current Year AMOUNT) * (1 + INTEREST_RATE) - CURRENT YEAR EXPENSES

Input Table:

```
YEAR    ACCT_ID AMOUNT  INTEREST_RATE   EXPENSES 
    2002    1       1000    0.05315         70  
    2003    1       1500    0.04213         80  
    2004    1       800     0.03215         75  
    2005    1       950     0.02563         78  
    2000    2       750     0.07532         79  
    2001    2       600     0.06251         75  
    2002    2       300     0.05315         70
```

Desired Output:

```
 YEAR   ACCT_ID AMOUNT  INTEREST_RATE   EXPENSES    INTERESTAMOUNT RUNNINGTOTAL
    2002    1       1000    0.05315         70          53.15          983.15
    2003    1       1500    0.04213         80          104.62         2507.77
    2004    1       800     0.03215         75          106.34         3339.11
    2005    1       950     0.02563         78          109.93         4321.04
    2000    2       750     0.07532         79          56.49          727.49
    2001    2       600     0.06251         75          82.98          1335.47
    2002    2       300     0.05315         70          86.93          1652.4
```

Comment: what is previous year's running total? i see it in both the calculations.

Comment: Sorry, for ACCT_ID 1 , the initial year would be 2002, which would not include a previous year, the running total would be calculated as:
 1000 * (1+0.05315)-70 = 983.15 
The Rolling compound calculation would begin in 2003, with 983.15 being the previous year calculation, (983.15+1500)*(1+0.04213)-80 = 2507.77.

Comment: You mention pl/sql in your question... I assume you mean Oracle SQL? pl/sql is a separate programming language, it can be used to solve your problem, but the general recommendation is to only use pl/sql when your problem can't be solved in plain SQL. Your current problem **can** be solved in plain SQL so you should not need pl/sql unless there are other considerations you didn't post. Please confirm.

Comment: vkp - I never practically used CTE/recursion before and your answer makes sense and works successfully for my needs.                     mathguy - Yes Oracle SQL, I just didn't want to exclude pl/sql because I have that option, but the plain SQL solution works.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is with a recursive cte.

```
with rownums as (select t.*
                 ,row_number() over(partition by acct_id order by yr) as rn 
                 from t) -- t is your tablename
,cte(rn,yr,acct_id,amount,interest_rate,expenses,running_total,interest_amount) as 
 (select rn,yr,acct_id,amount,interest_rate,expenses
  ,(amount*(1+interest_rate))-expenses
  ,amount*interest_rate
  from rownums
  where rn=1
  union all
  select t.rn,t.yr,t.acct_id,t.amount,t.interest_rate,t.expenses
  ,((c.running_total+t.amount)*(1+t.interest_rate))-t.expenses
  ,(c.running_total+t.amount)*t.interest_rate
  from cte c
  join rownums t on t.acct_id=c.acct_id and t.rn=c.rn+1
 )
select * from cte
```

[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/TJPQ48243)

- Generate row numbers using `row_number` function
- Calculate the interest and running total of the first row for each acct_id (anchor in the recursive cte).
- Join every row to the next one (ordered by ascending order of year column) for each account_id and compute the running total and interest for the subsequent rows.